# Visualizacionn de Videos en internet lento con PopOS en vmware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualización, gpu, vmware

actualmente instalado PopOS en mi maquina virtual VMware Workstation 16 Pro, y al iniciar youtube o cualquier página de videos, lo carga muy lento con cortes en la reproducción, en mi máquina virtual tengo instalado también Debian y Linux Lite los cuales reproducen perfectamente los videos, solo pasa este problema con PopOS, ya le instale open-vm-tools-desktop pensando que con eso se solucionaria pero igual, aparte instale el PopOS en otra VirtualBox pero igual la reproduccion es lenta**(bueno en virtualbox la reproduccion se ve bien por algo de 2 segundos aproximadamenete y luego viene los cortes pero en vmware es ahi al instante los cortes).**
A que se debe este problema comunidad, por eso pido ayuda a los que les ha pasado esto. Gracias.

Comment: Probablemente solo necesitas [configurar el video](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-E03ED27D-E469-4115-80E1-435125D6168B.html)

Comment: como seria ese procedimiento @Triby